# Infinite prime generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, generator

This code acts as an infinite generator of prime numbers.

As new prime numbers are found, they are added to a set. Then, a number *x* is found to be prime if none of the numbers in the prime set are factors of *x*. Only the primes less than or equal to the square root of *x* need to be checked.

```
import itertools
from math import sqrt   

class stream:
    """ Class of infinite streams. """

    def prime():
        """ Stream of prime numbers. """
        prime_set = {2} # Set of prime numbers that have been found
        yield 2 # First prime
        for x in itertools.count(3, 2): # Check odd numbers, starting with 3
            primes_below_sqrt = {i for i in prime_set if i <= sqrt(x)} 
            for prime in primes_below_sqrt:
                if x % prime == 0:
                    break # x is divisible by a prime factor, so it is not prime
            else:
                prime_set.add(x) # x has been shown to be prime
                yield x
```

Using the `itertools` recipe:

```
def take(iterable, n):
    """ Returns first n items of the iterable as a list. """
    return list(itertools.islice(iterable, n))
```

Output:

```
>>> take(stream.prime(), 10)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logic mostly looks sound. Some general Python style comments:

- I see no reason to put this function on a class – just make it a top-level function and be done with it. Even if you’re writing multiple infinite streams, group them in a single file, not on a class.
- Read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide. In particular, two spaces before inline comments, class names are uppercase.
- Your comments aren’t very helpful; they really just describe what the code is doing. It would be better to explain why the code was written that way. For example, replace:

  ```
  # Check odd numbers, starting with 3
  ```

  with:

  ```
  # We only need to check odd numbers, because all evens > 2 are not prime
  ```
- Use keyword arguments for clarity. Your call to `itertools.count()` is clearer like so:

  ```
  itertools.count(start=3, step=2)
  ```

  I was able to sort-of guess based on the comment, but keyword arguments always improve clarity and reduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

This is a performance issue:

> ```
> primes_below_sqrt = {i for i in prime_set if i <= sqrt(x)}
> ```

By using a set comprehension instead of a generator expression, you are actually making a copy of the subset.

Comment: Would the problem be fixed just by switching the curly brackets to round brackets?

Comment: Yes, that could fix the issue.